# Ghostscript giving "Ghostscript conversion Error" after executing correctly for the first time

Tags: ghostscript

I am facing a wierd issue when converting a pdf to image.I am executing the conversion code on pdf hover .It works well the first time and then starts giving me "ghostscript conversion error" from the next time.The code that gives the error is given below.

```
int result = InitAPI(gsInstancePtr, args.Length, args);
```

It returns an errorcode of -100. The Complete code is as below.

```
    public static void CallAPI(string[] args)
    {
        // Get a pointer to an instance of the Ghostscript API and run the API with the current arguments
        IntPtr gsInstancePtr;
        lock (resourceLock)
        {
            CreateAPIInstance(out gsInstancePtr, IntPtr.Zero);
            try
            {
                int result = InitAPI(gsInstancePtr, args.Length, args);

                if (result < 0)
                {
                    throw new ExternalException("Ghostscript conversion error", result);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Cleanup(gsInstancePtr);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Frees up the memory used for the API arguments and clears the Ghostscript API instance
    /// </summary>
    private static void Cleanup(IntPtr gsInstancePtr)
    {
        ExitAPI(gsInstancePtr);
        DeleteAPIInstance(gsInstancePtr);
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to leave the first 'arg' empty(blank)? Ghostscript ignores the first parameter (arg[0]) when it's called via API.

Answer (score 0):

Well,the first thin is, you aren't using Ghostscript, at least not directly. Possibly you are using Ghostscript.NET ?

From Ghostscript itself error -100 means a fatal error, additional information may be available on stdout or stderr, you need to capture and report that.

Comment: He is not using Ghostscript.NET. He is calling API directly via P/Invoke.

Comment: OK, how did you know that ?

Comment: Those function names cannot be found in the Ghostscript.NET, also, Ghostscript.NET takes care about creating, calling, exiting and deleting the Ghostscript instance.

Comment: That's fair enough, but it does suggest there's a considerable amount of code not being shared here, the body of the InitAPI() function would seem to be most useful here.